# how to remove the unwanted banner in wordpress static page

Tags: themes

hello i have checked how to remove the unwanted banner in my wordpress web site page. please tell me how do i do that. i have wasted more time to do this. but not found the clue. please check attached.

[image]

blue colored banner with text i need to remove.

Comment: What theme you are using? Whats the link to the page?